# Get list of custom fields and update their settings programatically

Tags: entities, 8, emails, configuration

I'm using D8's core contact form, I have added some custom fields and I want to change one of custom fields' settings config programatically.

I have tried this

```
\Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getFieldDefinitions('contact_form')
```

but I get error:

```
LogicException: Getting the base fields is not supported for entity type Contact form. in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityFieldManager->buildBaseFieldDefinitions() (line 204 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityFieldManager.php).
```

Is there any way to get list of fields and update their configs and settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

`$fields = \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getFieldDefinitions('contact_message', 'personal');`

You can change `personal` to your contact form bundle.